# PHPUnit autoloader conflict

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, netbeans-7

I can't use phpunit 4.7 in my project from netbeans 7.2 If i try to run the test it shows the error

> Warning: require_once(ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

I have my own autoloader which loads namespaced classes by structred as directory. PHPUnit probably using my autoloader to load its files and unable to find the classes. how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to write an autoloader that (tries to) load(s) classes it is not responsible for. You may do that but don't expect other autoloaders to work then.

Comment: can you elaborate more? how would i then load the classes which have to be tested?